# How to extract specific <li> element using Xpath or CSS?

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

How do I extract the information that is within the span that in turn is found inside the li?

```
<div class="col-md-offer-content">
 <ul class="params-list">
  <li>
   <ul class="main-list">
    <li>Preço 
       <span><strong>350 €</strong></span> 6 €/m²</li>
    <li>Área útil (m²) 
       <span><strong>60 m²</strong></span></li>
    <li>Tipologia 
       <span><strong>T1</strong></span></li>
   </ul>
```

I made this code: r

```
esponse.xpath ('// ul [@ class = "mainlist"] / li [span = "T1"] / text ()'). Extract ()
```

and the Output is: `['Typology']`

But in my case I want it to return the T1 and so I did:

```
response.xpath ('// ul [@ class = "main-list"] / span [li = "Tipology"] / text ()') .extract ()
```

but it does not return anything ... what am I doing wrong? any suggestion?

Comment: The text says "Tipologia", not "Tipology".

Answer (score 1):

you may just be able to do this:

```
esponse.xpath ('// ul [@ class = "mainlist"] / [span="T1"] / text ()'). Extract ()
```

**OR**

```
//ul[@id='mainlist']//li[3]//span
```

**OR**

if you add a class to the span

```
<div class="col-md-offer-content">
 <ul class="params-list">
  <li>
   <ul class="main-list">
    <li>Preço 
       <span><strong>350 €</strong></span> 6 €/m²</li>
    <li>Área útil (m²) 
       <span><strong>60 m²</strong></span></li>
    <li>Tipologia 
       <span class="thisSpan"><strong>T1</strong></span></li>
   </ul>
```

then use xpath like this:

```
esponse.xpath ('// ul [@ class = "mainlist"] / span[@class="thisSpan"] / text ()'). Extract ()
```

**OR**
In CSS: `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ul#mainlist span.thisSpan"));`

Comment: This code is from a website where I am taking the information to create the crawler ... can I add that piece of code?

Comment: And if I do this code :  response.xpath('// ul [@ class = "mainlist"] / [span="Tipology"] / text ()'). Extract () , appears this error : ValueError: XPath error: Invalid expression

Comment: so this code works : '//ul[@class="main-list"]//li[3]//span'. But prints: <span> <strong> T1 </ span> </ strong>. How do I shoot these bullets?

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath = '//ul[@class="main-list"]//li[3]//text()'
val = response.xpath(xpath).extract_first()
```

You'll get only third li's value.
if you want a list having every li's value.
try: 
    `xpath = "//ul[@class="main-list"]//li//text()"`
    `li_vals_list = response.xpath(xpath).extract()`
 with this method, you will get every li's val and can get your desired li's val simply by indexing :)

Thanks.